# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is not being called

Tags: spring-security

I am working through several tutorials to implement my own security within my project.

The problem is, as configured the `system.out.println` calls within the class the extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` are not being hit. Which means the security class is not being called at all.  There are no error messages and I'm also able to navigate to any page within the site without the authorization redirecting to the login page.  Also, the login page just does a post and takes me to the home page of the site.

Here is the custom web security configurer adapter:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    ShopmeUserDetailsService shopmeUserDetailsService;
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new ShopmeUserDetailsService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenicationProvider() {
        System.out.println("In Dao auth security");
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        
        return authProvider;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In configure security");
        //auth.authenticationProvider(authenicationProvider());
        //auth.userDetailsService(shopmeUserDetailsService);
        
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1")
                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
                    .roles("USER")
                    .and()            
                .withUser("user2")
                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2Pass"))
                    .roles("USER")
                    .and() 
                .withUser("admin")
                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode("adminPass"))
                    .roles("ADMIN");
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In configure security auth");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() //all URLs are allowed by any authenticated user, no role restrictions.
                .and()
            .formLogin()  //enable form based authentication
                .loginPage("/login") //use a custom login URI
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .permitAll(true) //login URI can be accessed by anyone
                .and()
            .logout() //default logout handling
                .permitAll(); //allow all as it will be accessed when user is not logged in anymore
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("In configure ignorings");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**" );
    }
}
```

Here is the main app class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@EntityScan({"com.shopme.common.entity", "com.shopme.admin.user"})
public class ShopmeBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShopmeBackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My main controller:

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("")
    public String viewHomePage() {
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String viewLoginPage() {
        System.out.println("In viewLoginPage method - MainController");
        return "login";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        System.out.println("login attempt");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And finally my other controller for the admin pages:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.shopme.admin.FileUploadUtil;
import com.shopme.common.entity.Role;
import com.shopme.common.entity.User;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    //private final java.nio.file.Path root = Paths.get("user_photos");
    
    //Updated method to list the first page of users
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String listFirstPage(Model model) {
        
        return listUsersByPage(1, model, null);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/users/new")
    public String newUser(Model model) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("new User method");
        
        List<Role> roles = userService.listRoles();
        
        //System.out.println(multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename());      
        
        //String fileName = 
StringUtils.cleanPath(multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        
        //String uploadDir = "user_photos";
        
        //FileUploadUtil.saveFile(uploadDir, fileName, multiPartFile);
        
        //Files.copy(multiPartFile.getInputStream(), ((java.nio.file.Path) 
this.root).resolve(multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
        
        User user = new User();
        user.setEnabled(true);
        
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Create New User");
        
        return "user_form";
    }
     
    @PostMapping("/users/save")
    public String saveUser(User user, RedirectAttributes redirect, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multiPartFile) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println(multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename());        
        
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        
        String uploadDir = "user_photos";
        
        FileUploadUtil.saveFile(uploadDir, fileName, multiPartFile);
        
        //Files.copy(multiPartFile.getInputStream(), ((java.nio.file.Path) this.root).resolve(multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
        
        userService.save(user);
        
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("message", "User has been saved successfully!");
        
        return "redirect:/users/page/1?keyword=" + user.getId();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/users/edit/{id}")
    public String editUser(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirect){
        try {
            Optional<User> user = userService.getUserById(id);
            List<Role> roles = userService.listRoles();

            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
            model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Edit User (ID: " + id + ")");

            return "user_form";
            
        } catch (UserNotFoundException ex) {
            redirect.addFlashAttribute("message", ex.getMessage());

            return "redirect:/users";
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("users/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable(name="id") Integer id, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirect) {
        
        userService.deleteUserById(id);
        
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("message", "User has been deleted successfully!");

        return "redirect:/users";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/users/{id}/enabled/{status}")
    public String updateUserEnabledStatus(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,   @PathVariable("status") boolean enabled, RedirectAttributes redirect) {
        
        userService.updateUserEdabledStatus(id, enabled);
        String status = enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled";
        String message = "THe user Id " + id + " has been " + status;
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("message", message);
        return "redirect:/users";       
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/page/{pageNumber}")
    public String listUsersByPage(@PathVariable(name = "pageNumber") int pageNumber,    Model model, @Param("keyword") String keyword) {
        Page<User> page = userService.listByPage(pageNumber, keyword);
        
        List<User> userPagedList = page.getContent();
        
        System.out.println("Pagenumber: " + pageNumber);
        System.out.println("Total Elements: " + page.getTotalElements());
        System.out.println("Totals Pages: " + page.getTotalPages());
        
        long startCount = (pageNumber - 1) * UserService.USERS_PER_PAGE +1;
        long endCount = startCount + UserService.USERS_PER_PAGE -1;
        
        if(endCount > page.getTotalElements()){
            endCount = page.getTotalElements();
        }
        
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNumber);
        model.addAttribute("startCount", startCount);
        model.addAttribute("endCount", endCount);
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());
        model.addAttribute("users", userPagedList);
        model.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
        
        return "users";
    } //end listUserByPage
    
    @GetMapping("/users/export/csv")
    public void exportToCSV(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        List<User> userList = userService.listAll();
        
        UserCsvExporter exporter = new UserCsvExporter();
        
        exporter.export(userList, response);
    } //end exportToCsv
    
    @GetMapping("/users/export/excel")
    public void exportToExcel(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        List<User> userList = userService.listAll();
        
        UserExcelExporter exporter = new UserExcelExporter();
        
        exporter.export(userList, response);
    } //end exportToExcel
    
    @GetMapping("/users/export/pdf")
    public void exportToPdf(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        List<User> userList = userService.listAll();
        
        UserPdfExporter exporter = new UserPdfExporter();
        
        exporter.export(userList, response);
        
    } //end exportToPdf
} //end of class
```

I've spent two days investigating this with no results... any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you exclude Spring Security auto configuration? Without it Spring Security is not working.

Comment: I have since removed that, it was there for testing purposes to exclude the login functionality.

Answer (score -2):

I figured out why this was not working, well at least I have it working with this solution.

I included the WebSecurityConfig.class in the start-up class of the project as shown below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"com.shopme.common.entity", "com.shopme.admin.user"})
public class ShopmeBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Class[]
                {ShopmeBackendApplication.class, 
                WebSecurityConfig.class}, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is not how you should solve it, you have most likely something wrong in your application and i suggest you upload it to github and show it to us because you will probably have more problems down the line with this solution. Downvote since this is not the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: I agree you on that, I will work on getting project uploaded to github and as you mentioned, something else has gone wrong, not the component scan will not pickup a new controller that I added to the project.  The existing controllers work, but not new one. Will let you know when project on github...thank you for assisting.

Comment: All the problems you are having is pointing me to that you have a uncommon project structure. Spring will (by default) scan the same and all subdirectories from the main class for possible annotated classes. But i cant see your project structure

Comment: Toektmmlare --- You were on the right track, I was following a tutorial and somewhere along the line the project file become corrupted, so I delete the project file and then recreated it, all errors and random errors have gone away.